# Use Facebook APP Authentication to automatically login to Mobile Website?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, authentication

Is there anyway to access the native Facebook application (on iOS or Android) to retrieve login authentication on a mobile website that has permissions already?

The cache and data of browser has been emptied.

User hits http://example.com/

example.com checks to see if there is a token in browser to identify the user and see if user is logged into Facebook. this fails

example.com accesses the Facebook app and gets user token?

User is logged onto the site automatically.

I know this is more then likely impossible however I thought I would check with the experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is for Android...

You can use the Facebook SDK to do single sign on (SSO) - and in fact this is the default for  `authorize()`.

If you call `authorize()` with SSO / default, the Facebook SDK will detect whether the Facebook App is installed, and attempt to login via the Faceook App. If the Facebook App is present and logged in, then the SDK will retrieve the access token from the Facebook App, will not do a separate browser login, and will use the access token on subsequent Facebook requests.

Does that do what you need?

Comment: This actually seems perfect, you said Android, is that android only?

Comment: I have only used the Facebook SDK on Android, so have no idea whether the authorize exists / works the same on iPhone. But you could download / browse the iPhone SDK and check it out?

Comment: if the access token is retrieved from the Facebook App how come my app doesn't have all the permissions that the Facebook App has?